# Database config in xml file

Tags: php, mysql, xml

I need to create DB config file in xml for connecting with db in php application.
And I create something like this

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <connection>
        <host>localhost</host>
        <user>antin</user>
        <password>password</password>
        <dbase>database</dbase>
    </connection>
```

Then I can get host, user, password and dbase using SimpleXML. But I think that it isn't unsafe because everyone can parse this file. I think that that xml file have to be something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <connection>
        <host><![CDATA[localhost]]></host>
        <user><![CDATA[antin]]></user>
        <password><![CDATA[password]]></password>
        <dbase><![CDATA[database]]></dbase>
    </connection>
```

Can you help me to understand the right way for creation xml config file and getting connection info?
Thanks!

Comment: If you hide the file using .htaccess that would be one less worry. You could also use mcrypt_encrypt() and mcrypt_decrypt() to encrypt/decrypt the values.

Comment: Please demonstrate using mcrypt_encrypt() and mcrypt_decrypt() to encrypt/decrypt the values of database connection from xml config file

Comment: The usual approach is to use `.php` file to store the DB credentials. This way nobody can just open the file and see the credentials in plain text.

Comment: @Antoan Milkov I understand it. But I have task to use xml

Comment: So what exactly is the question? How to create an XML? Please be specific.

Comment: The question is next. What is the right way for creation database(MySQL) connecting config file using xml?